# Rewrite Trailing Slash Issue

Tags: apache

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^(\d*)/(.*) /page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

It all works fine. But the moment I type site.com/342/my-page/ (with the trailing slash) I get a 404.

I need the trailing slash as optional. I.e it will redirect to the correct page with or without the slash.

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^(\d*)/(.*)/?$ /page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

.* is greedy, so it will eat your trailing slash even if it does not have to. You have to force it to stay away like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d*)/(.*[^/])/?$ /page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

This is ensure that $2 is never ending with a slash